# Maths undergrad dissertation - minimal surfaces

Tags: curvature, general-relativity, minimal-surfaces

I'm a third year maths undergrad writing a dissertation on minimal surfaces, and their application in space. Would anyone be willing to read through it (so far) and give me any feedback? positive or critical!
I am nearing the end now, but want to check if I've not missed anything fundamental!

Thank you in advance

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ktko43j7ylr3pum/dissertation.pdf?n=231814037

I hope that works!

Comment: Also not sure if this belongs in the maths or physics section?

Comment: If it's of mathematical nature, and not strictly physical, then it belongs here. You should post a link to your dissertation, though, so people can take a look at it.

Comment: way to much history if you ask me. also you should cite at least some books. also your layout is in many ways not consistent. nicely written though

Comment: Okay that's a good comment! Please note I have fully referenced the essay, it's just not attached to this document!

Comment: In terms of the layout, this is the first time I have used Latex to write a document so I'm not that comfortable with it. Is there anything in particular about the layout as to it's consistency?

Comment: I have only looked at the layout, without reading it. It looks good, except that you have a couple formulas that are too long (you will get some notes saying "overfull hbox" when compiling because of that). I would advise you to divide them on more than a line, maybe using array or eqnarray.

Comment: okay, are there any particular equations that stand out? also what is 'array'? and how do I apply it?

Comment: You have 5 or 6 around, but the worst ones are probably the ones at p.18 and 19. "array" is used to make an array of objects (or equations). Take a look here: http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/Matrices.html

Comment: Okay, I've just tried to apply an 'array' thing, and it keeps giving me an 'error' if I have this : 

\begin{center}
$I = \dfrac{2}{5} M R^2 \approx 8.02 \times 10^{37} \text{kg} \, \text{m}^2 $\\
$\omega = \displaystyle{\frac{2\pi}{86164\,\text{s}}} = 7.29 \times 10^{−5}\,\text{rad}\,\text{s}^{-1}$\\
$r = 6371 + 642 = 7013 \text{km}.$
\end{center}

How do I 'array' it?

Answer (score 0):

To use the "array" environment:

```
$$\begin{array}{ll}
    lhs1 & = rhs1\\
    lhs2 & = rhs2
    \end{array}$$
```

The `{ll}` means that you want to have $2$ columns (there are two letters in the brackets), both aligned on the left (`l` for left, `r` for right, `c` for centered). The `&` means "go to the next slot", the `\\` means "go to the next line". Notice that I put the `$$` outside of the array ambient.

Comment: Okay I think I fixed it! Thank you!